# Not able to print full HTML page using window.print() there are 3 page content but only 1 page got data other are blank

Tags: html, css

Not able to print full HTML page using window.print() there are 3 page content but only 1 page got data other are blank.i am using below CSS file is there any problem with that.Please help me with that.

```
canvas {
    display: none
}

@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    canvas {
        visibility: visible;
        margin-top: 30%;
    }
    .form-control {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .final-results * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .spider-chart * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .final-results,
    .form-control {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Please include the HTML as well

Comment: You declare `canvas { display: none }` but `canvas { visibility: visible; }` without changing the display style. May be as simple as `canvas { visibility: visible; display: initial; }`